# Trying to pass a parameter from php file and tag to script tag

Tags: javascript, php

Im trying to pass a parameter inside function with on click to a script tag, btw I do not want to use the global $result. I only want to use it from the parameter.
Heres my code:

```
<?php
  $results = [person1:{}] // a bunch of different people in array
  while($result in $results) //pseudo code to get each person in results
 <div>
  <input type="button" value="Submit"     onclick="changeConfirmed($result)">
 </form>';
 echo '</div>';
?>

 <script>
    function changeConfirmed(val){
    $maj=val['major'];
    alert("Your major is: " + major);
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: The `$result` is array?

Comment: Yes it is an array

Comment: Please add a console.log(val); inside the `changeConfirmed()` and provide the output.

Comment: Have you got some dummy data just to show the structure of $result so I dont have to think too hard :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

[passing php variable in onClick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621231/passing-php-variable-in-onclick-function)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP variables only live on the server. They are completely separate from the JavaScript variables on the client. The only mechanism for passing values from the server to the client is through the contents of the web page (or through specially requested behind-the-scenes web content through AJAX).
By the way, You can convert this array into JSON and then pass this string to function.
Check this way:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="changeConfirmed(json_encode($result))">
```

Comment: Thank you, but that still doesn't work for me. For some reason whenever i have a parameter it completely breaks the function even if I don't call the parameter.

Comment: @BkRazor, what are you saying, can you explain (Sorry for it, but i did not understand)

Comment: Sorry I didnt give enough info i created another post, but I will update this one also

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your "array" is and based upon what I can gather from the question, a "mockup" $result array could have the simple form of...

```
$result = [ 'major' => 'General' ];
```

And the form code simplified to the format...

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick=changeConfirmed('<?= json_encode($result); ?>')>
</form>
```

Then the jQuery being (and I just beat this to death to get something working after scouring Google and trying lots of things... So it might not be the optimal way)

```
<script>
    function changeConfirmed(val) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(val);
        console.log(val);
        var major = obj.major;
        alert("Your major is: " + major);
    }
</script>
```

Results in the alert stating that "Your major is  General".

But I am gathering that you would be using something that uniquely identifies each input row like a number.

If I am way off track to what you are after, at least I learned another little trick. :)

Comment: This seems like your on to something, and I can see this working, but this input is within an echo funtion which is already surronded with single quotes

Comment: That's simple enough, if provide the actual code then I can update my answer.